# PHP email validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using radio buttons to display my form's textbox. I added a PHP script to validate the email and on completion, open another page. But nothing seems to be working. It shows the error message for when the textbox is empty, even when the submit button hasn't been pressed, and it refreshes the page if the email format isn't correct.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$emailErr = "";
$email = "";

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
    else{
        header("Location:create.php")
    }
  }

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>
```

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var chkYes1 = document.getElementById("chkYes1");
  var dvtext1 = document.getElementById("dvtext1");
  var chkYes2 = document.getElementById("chkYes2");
  var dvtext2 = document.getElementById("dvtext2");
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  dvtext1.style.display = chkYes1.checked || chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
  dvtext2.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
  btn1.style.display = chkYes1.checked ? "block" : "none";
  btn2.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="content login-container">
  <div class="form-login">
     <label for="chkYes1">
        <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
        I am new on Swadonline
      </label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="dvtext1" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
        Please enter your Email Address *
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="email" />
      </div>
      <button style="display: none" id="btn1" class="btn third" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">CONTINUE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is any of that CSS relevant to the question?

Comment: Yes the CSS is relevant to the question Padre, as some classes in the html require them

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid; your `</form>` comes too late. And to prevent your error (`$emailError`) from showing, you should only be outputting it if it's set with `if (isset()` :)

Comment: @nnnnnn I just edited it

Comment: Thanks. It's easier to help if there are less distractions from the code you are asking about.

Comment: can you show your error info here?

Comment: @KrisRoofe error info?

Answer (score 0):

In html change this line

```
<button style="display: none" id="btn1" class="btn third" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">CONTINUE</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit"  style="display: none" id="btn1" class="btn third"  name="my_form_submit" value="CONTINUE">
```

Now in your php change as below:

```
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$emailErr = "";
$email = "";
if(isset($_POST['my_form_submit'])){ // only check validation if form has been submitted, else don't validate

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
        else{
            header("Location:create.php");
        }
      }

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out mate, but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I've taken this route for form submissions once upon a time, since then I would highly recommend setting up [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for any project.

- For the email part: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is relatively easy to set up and has never let me down.
- For the Validation, all you have to do is add a 'required' attribute to the forms, to my knowledge, the browser will do the rest :)

Hope this in any way helps!